# How to set the paragraph of itext pdf file as rectangle with background color in Java

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, itext

I am designing a pdf report using itext library.I have implemented a paragraph in it.Now as per my requirement i have to set this paragraph inside rectangular box with background color but i am not able to do it..

Here is my Itext code in java...

```
Font f = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 25.0f, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.CYAN);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Total Cost:" + dbsumcallcost, f);
document.add(p);
```

Please guys help me.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need a `Chunk` to do that:

```
Font f = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 25.0f, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.WHITE);
Chunk c = new Chunk("Total Cost:" + dbsumcallcost, f);
c.setBackground(BaseColor.RED);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph(c);
document.add(p);
```

See the [ChunkBackground](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/ChunkBackground) example and the [resulting PDF document](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/chunk_background.pdf).

You can fine-tune the rectangle by using a slightly different `setBackground()` method: http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Chunk.html#setBackground%28com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29

Comment: Thank u sir for ur answer now rectangle is coming but Total Cost:" + dbsumcallcost is not coming in rectangle

Comment: That's strange. I'll try making an example. Give me a moment.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example. You can clearly see the white text on the red background. Are you sure you are using different colors for text and background?

Answer (score 4):

**Updated to Feb - 2021 and iText7.**

You can set directly the background color of the paragraph:

Generate a `Color()` object (RGB in this case)

```
Color bColor = new DeviceRgb(250, 210, 73);
```

Set the color to the `Paragraph` element

```
paragraphObj.setBackgroundColor(bColor);
```

Spent some time looking for this, hope it helps someone.